# Looking for an example for bounded operators

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded operator, where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces.

Then could it happen that $\overline{TO_X(1)}\not\subset TO_X(2)$? Here $O_X(r):=\{x\in X:\|x\|<r\}$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687288/the-closure-of-the-image-of-the-unit-sphere) answer might be helpful